# Design Industrial Process Controller for Testability

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, performance-testing, api, embedded

We are currently developing a new industrial process controller for applications with very low cycle times (<50us). The embedded software that runs on this controller shall be validated automatically in the future. The controller is then seen as a black box that can only be accessed through its I/O and API. From a software testing perspective (CI/CD), I would like to give our hardware developers some input so that they can design the controller so that the embedded software running on it becomes as "testable" as possible. Which interfaces, functions, etc. should a controller offer in terms of hardware and software in order to achieve this goal? Are there any general design specifications in this regard?

Comment: Testing is a risk evaluation activity. Thus the testability of a product will depend on which risks do you want to assess. Besides the cycle time, what do you want to continuously investigate?

Comment: The major test object is the software running on the controller. For this software we mainly run funtional tests to ensure that it fulfills the requirements of our customers. In addition, we want to do performance testing for specific scenarios with increasing controller load